# How to have a Sign Up box on the current page when you click on sign up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how to get a 'sign up' box (overlay) in the center of my index page when an enduser has no account and wants to sign up by clicking on 'sign up' ? And after having completed the sign up form, it should stay on the same page.

I think I know how to do the latter one, but the first one I do not know completely.

**All I need is some direction or some clues, with that, I can figure it out by myself.**

What I want it to look like is this: 
[image]

I mean.. do I give the sign-up element a specific id, use that with a JS and tell the page to "#" so that a JS can run on the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for. If you click on the button, you'll get a popup form with a overlay. And, if you click on the overlay, it will hide. I've finished most of the work for you! Now you just need to finish it! :)

```js
$('#sign-up').click(function(){
 var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).fadeToggle('fast');
});

$('#sign-up-popup').click(function(){
 $(this).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

```css
.sign-up{
    border:1px solid black;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.popup-overlay{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
}

.sign-up-form-container{
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -o-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-50%);
    transform: translatey(-50%);
}

.sign-up-form-container input[type='text']{
    display:block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="sign-up" class="sign-up" href="#sign-up-popup">Sign Up (Click me for popup!)</a>

<div id="sign-up-popup" class="popup-overlay">
    <div class="sign-up-form-container">
    <form>
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <hr/>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" />
        <br/>
        <input type="text" />
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Sign Up" />
    </form>
    
</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: That JS is exactly what I was looking for! I am glad you understood my logic, thank you very much bro.